# nvcc fatal : '--ptxas-options=-v': expected a number

Tags: cuda, nvcc, pycuda, faster-rcnn

Getting the `nvcc fatal   : '--ptxas-options=-v': expected a number` error when I try to build [a Windows port of Faster-RCNN](https://github.com/MrGF/py-faster-rcnn-windows). You may reach the setup file (which is a Python script) directly from [here](https://github.com/MrGF/py-faster-rcnn-windows/blob/master/lib/setup_cuda.py).

Software Environment:

```
- CUDA v10.1
- VS 2019
- Python 3.7
- Windows 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This configuration line is no longer correct with CUDA 10.1:

```
nvcc_compile_args = ['-O', '--ptxas-options=-v', '-arch=sm_35', '-c', '--compiler-options=-fPIC']
```

That will generate a nvcc compile command that looks like this:

```
nvcc -O ...
```

With CUDA 10.0 and prior, such a command was legal.  With CUDA 10.1 it is not.  This switch passes the optimization level for host code, so barring any reason not to, I would recommend passing `-O3` here:

```
nvcc_compile_args = ['-O3', '--ptxas-options=-v', '-arch=sm_35', '-c', '--compiler-options=-fPIC']
```

The relevant doc link is [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior-optimize)